# How do I distribute values of an array in three columns?

Tags: php, arrays

I need this output..

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

I want to use array function like `array(1,2,3,4,5,6)`. If I edit this array like `array(1,2,3)`, it means the output need to show like

```
1 2 3
```

The concept is maximum 3 column only. If we give `array(1,2,3,4,5)`, it means the output should be

```
1 3 5 
2 4
```

Suppose we will give `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, then it means output is

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

that is, maximum 3 column only. Depends upon the the given input, the rows will be created with 3 columns.

Is this possible with PHP? I am doing small Research & Development in array functions. I think this is possible. Will you help me?

For more info:
* input: `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)`
* output:

```
1  6   11 
2  7   12 
3  8   13 
4  9   14 
5  10
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a foreach/for/while loop, and each time you have outputted your desired amount on that line you simply insert a newline in the output.

Comment: could you be more clear on what you want. Is there a specific condition on how you want them displayed???

Comment: Please clarify your question, it doesn't really make sense.  There are many ways to get that output, but since your array contains all 1's, it's impossible to tell what order you want the output in, and what the significance of that output is.

Comment: will you please give vote up for my question and release me for asking questions in stack(due to this negative votes my account lost the question making option).Now I can't ask able to ask questions..I love this place & i want to survive here.Here after i'll try to ask with Good English.please help me friends...

Comment: Just so that people are aware before they try to close this [as a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463607/how-do-i-print-values-of-an-array-in-threee-rows), the OP edited his 1st question to look like the above ***after*** it was closed, so perhaps this isn't really a dup?

Comment: don't close it.I Want Answer.Please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a loop that will automatically insert a new line on each three elements:

```
$values = array(1,1,1,1,1);

foreach($values as $i => $value) {
  printf('%-4d', $value);

  if($i % 3 === 2) echo "\n";
}
```

**EDIT:** Since you added more information, here's what you want:

```
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5);

for($line = 0; $line < 2; $line++) {
  if($line !== 0) echo "\n";

  for($i = $line; $i < count($values); $i+=2) {
    printf('%-4d', $values[$i]);
  }
}
```

And if you want to bundle all that in a function:

```
function print_values_table($array, $lines = 3, $format = "%-4d") {
  $values = array_values($array);
  $count = count($values);

  for($line = 0; $line < $lines; $line++) {
    if($line !== 0) echo "\n";

    for($i = $line; $i < $count; $i += $lines) {
      printf($format, $values[$i]);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is a modified version which will limit the numbers of columns to 3.

```
function print_values_table($array, $maxCols = 3, $format = "%-4d") {
  $values = array_values($array);
  $count = count($values);
  $lines = ceil($count / $maxCols);

  for($line = 0; $line < $lines; $line++) {
    if($line !== 0) echo "\n";

    for($i = $line; $i < $count; $i += $lines) {
      printf($format, $values[$i]);
    }
  }
}
```

So, the following:

```
$values = range(1,25);
print_array_table($values);
```

Will output this:

```
1   10  19  
2   11  20  
3   12  21  
4   13  22  
5   14  23  
6   15  24  
7   16  25  
8   17  
9   18
```

Comment: this is so only the output of 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: No no no! The requirements are very clear, 3 one's on top row, 2 on the bottom row. I ran out of paper figuring this one out, sure would hate to see you get by so easily.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i need much more efficient way to implement like Using Loop within Loop.Just try to make that..will you?

Comment: @Ramkumar: My answer IS the most efficient way. You cannot write to two lines at once.

Comment: in suppose we implement very large array(){10000 records) means  it'll help to get answer?

Comment: @Ramkumar: The size of the array doesn't matter. In both my examples, I'm only looping through the array **once**. **`O(n)`**

Comment: you are correct...so no options to implement like `for{...for...} }`?

Comment: @Ramkumar: Well, if you really want nested loops... One `for` for the lines and one for the values. It still going to be `O(n)`.

Comment: O(n) means? sorry friend i really don't know.

Comment: @Ramkumar: In simple terms, it means that the number of statements depending on the array size is equal to the amount of elements in that array.

Comment: @Andrew Moore +1 for patience ;-)

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to cut the array into chunks, representing the columns, and then print the values in row order:

```
$cols = array_chunk($arr, ceil(count($arr)/3));
for ($i=0, $n=count($cols[0]); $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo $cols[0][$i];
    if (isset($cols[1][$i])) echo $cols[1][$i];
    if (isset($cols[2][$i])) echo $cols[2][$i];
}
```

If you don’t want to split your array, you can also do it directly:

```
for ($c=0, $n=count($arr), $m=ceil($n/3); $c<$m; $c++) {
    echo $arr[$c];
    for ($r=$m; $r<$n; $r+=$m) {
        echo $arr[$c+$r];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to chunk it by `ceil(count($arr) / 3)`. If you chunk it by 3 you can't have the flow go downward.

Comment: @JohnP: What are you referring to?

Comment: The first solution, `$cols = array_chunk($arr, 3);`. You need to chunk it by `ceil(count($arr) / 3)` not 3, then you can simply iterate through the loops and you can get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
"{$a[0]} {$a[1]} {$a[2]}\n{$a[3]} {$a[4]}";
```

or

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
"{$a[0]} {$a[1]} {$a[2]}".PHP_EOL."{$a[3]} {$a[4]}";
```

or

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$second_row_start = 3; // change to vary length of rows
foreach( $a as $index => $value) {
  if($index == $second_row_start) echo PHP_EOL;
  echo "$value ";
}
```

or, perhaps if you want a longer array split into columns of 3?

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
$row_length = 3; // change to vary length of rows
foreach( $a as $index => $value) {
  if($index%$row_length == 0) echo PHP_EOL;
  echo "$value ";
}
```

which gives

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
10 11 12 
13
```

Comment: pls check my question...the vaues are 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I feel sorry for you buddy. +1 for taking the time to _enumerate all the possibilities_.

Comment: heh heh - we all had to start somewhere, right? Ramkumar, I think the issue is that your question is too narrow - people want to help, but they're not sure what is the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi dycey,Thanks for helping me.@Andrew Moore answer is correct but,for efficient outputwe need to create,like loop within loop for Examlpe:  `for{...for...} }`. is this clear?

Answer (score 1):

one solution is :
your array has N elements, and you want 3 columns, so you can get the value of each cell with $myarray[ column_index + (N/3) + line_index ] (with one or two loops for columns and lines, at least for lines)
I hope this will help you
Bye

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I whipped up. I'm pretty sure this could be more easily accomplished if you were using HTML lists, I've assumed you can't use them.

```
$arr    = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, 15, 16);
$max    = count($arr);
$cols   = 3;
$block  = ceil($max / $cols);
for ($i = 0; $i < $block ; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i] . ' ';

    for ($j = 1; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        $nexKey = $i  + $block * $j;
        if (!isset($arr[$nexKey])) break;   
        echo $arr[$nexKey] . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

<strike>**NOTE** : You can easily refactor the code inside the loop that uses `$nexkey` variable by making it into a loop itself so that it works for any number of columns. I've hardcoded it.</strike>

Uses loops now.

Comment: You comment worked out for me for this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478678/divide-rows-from-db-against-fixed-li-columns-in-php  So if you want the points.. ;)