# How do I print values of an array in Three Columns?

Tags: php, arrays, math

I Need This Output..

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

I Want to use Array function like array(1,2,3,4,5,6). If i Edit this array like array(1,2,3) means the output need to show like

```
1 2 3
```

The concept is Maximum 3 Column only.If we give array(1,2,3,4,5) Means the output should be

```
1 3 5 
2 4
```

Suppose we will give array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) Means o/p is

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Maximum 3 Column only.Depends upon the the given input the rows will be create with 3 column.Is This is Possible with PHP?Am Doing small Research & Development in Array Functions.I think this possible.Will you help me?
For more info:I/p :array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) 
O/P:

```
1  6   11 
2  7   12 
3  8   13 
4  9   14 
5  10  15
```

Comment: This is not a mathematics question. It looks like it would be more appropriate for stackoverflow, or one of the other stackexchange sites dealing with programming.

Comment: Will you please Migrate this question to Stackoverflow?I don't have permission to do that..Please..:)

Comment: I don't have the power to do that either, yet, but I have flagged for moderator attention, they will be able to.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6450810/469210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting number of rows is as easy as *[ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function)(total number of elements / elements per row)*. All you need to do is to copy the elements from one one-dimensional array to an other two-dimensional array. One possible method:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
);
$col = 3;
$row = ceil(count($input) / $col);
$output = array();
while(count($input)){
    $output[] = array_splice($input, 0, $row);
}
for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
    $temp = array();
    for($j = 0; $j < $col; $j++) {
        if (isset($output[$j][$i])) {
            $temp[] = $output[$j][$i];
        }
    }
    echo implode(", ", $temp) . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
1, 6, 11
2, 7, 12
3, 8, 13
4, 9
5, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_chunk() function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$example_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$chunked_array = array_chunk($example_array, 3));
```

$chunked_array will be an array with 2 subarrays: array(array(a,b,c), array(d,e))