# Divide rows from db against fixed <li> columns in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I did a search, but nothing I saw was the same or could help.

I've got rows coming in from a db and what I want to do is divide that into 5 columns.

This is what I have, it only shows 4 columns and well I'm stuck....

`$result` is the array containing the db rows.

```
$divider = floor(count($result) / 5);
$roundup = ceil(count($result) / 5);

$start = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $divider; $i++) {
    $splResult = array_slice($result, $start, $roundup);    

    $content .= '<li>';         

    foreach ($splResult as $row) {          
        $content = "content goes here";
    }

    $content .= '</li>';                

    $start = $start + $roundup;
}
```

So lets say I have 16 items coming in.  The result I would like to get is (or at least better distributed):

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
        <div>15</div>
        <div>16</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Note: what comes in from the db could range from 0 to 100 rows.  But it must always be divided in 5 columns.

Comment: Don't you love it when you post a question, you do find something that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450810/how-do-i-distribute-values-of-an-array-in-three-columns/6463658#6463658

Comment: If you have any css or anything like that on the page that could be limiting the number of columns. If the php functions works fine it just doesn't format how you want I'd try to maybe add some basic html or css formatting to the output to see if you can get it to format itself right. I recently had a formatting issue like this in which photo's had to be fetched within a page for a gallery view. Had to change to html and css to get it all to fit itself correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, there are no CSS/JS here.  Its purely a PHP problem.  I want 5 colums of <li> tags.  Even with the link I just posted, still having trouble implementing it.  So if anyone decides to answer this, thanks ;)

Comment: Got something better from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450810/how-do-i-distribute-values-of-an-array-in-three-columns/6464984#6464984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. No guarantees that it's the best.

```
$cnt  = count($result);

// creates an array which evenly distributes numbers across 
// a series of entries.
$nums = array(0,0,0,0,0);
for( $i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++ ) $nums[ $i % 5 ]++;

echo '<ol>';
$k = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )
{
    echo '<li>';
    // iterate through the count for this column.
    for( $j = 0; $j < $nums[ $i ]; $j++ )
    {
        echo '<div>' . $result[ $k ] . '<div>';
        $k++;
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: Thanks, better code than the other answer.  However, when I have 16 rows returned.  It outputs 19, which gives 17-19 undefined in my logs and also it skips some rows in the db so only 12 items are shown. I removed the last $k++ after the echo (where you made the comment) and it works fine.