# display format of input using php

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I need to display array of 10 numbers in three columns. if i add another number some like, 11 it must add below 10. as numbers increasing row can be increased not the column, can any one say?

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

am getting 10 in fourth column, but i need it in third column. and row will get increased like

```
1 4 8
2 5 9
3 6 10
4 7
```

Comment: can you give an example output of what you really want?

Comment: Three columns means 10 ends up on a row of its own. Why must 11 be displayed *under* it? Can you show an example?

Comment: I swear the same questions was asked very recently, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: Here you go: [How do I distribute values of an array in three columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450810/how-do-i-distribute-values-of-an-array-in-three-columns) Browser history search function FTW.

Comment: was asked by two persons in the same location, any chance it's homework from the same class? :D (I know India is big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Output in table..

```
<?php
$arr = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "11", "12", "13");

$row= ceil(count($arr)/3);
echo "<table border='1'>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $i ."</td>";
    $k = 0;
    $pre = 0;
  for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) {
    if($pre == 0)
      $pre = $k = $i + $row;
    else
      $pre = $pre + $row;

    if($pre <= max($arr))
      echo "<td>". $arr[$pre-1] ."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Output will be:

```
1   6   11
2   7   12
3   8   13
4   9
5   10
```

Comment: instead of writing the enitre array like this $arr = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "11", "12", "13");, u can use $arr = range(1,13);

Comment: good suggestion. but here my goal was to display data in desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
$arr = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "11", "12", "13", "14");

$row= ceil(count($arr)/3);

for($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    $k = 0;
    $pre = 0;
  for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) {
    if($pre == 0)
      $pre = $k = $i + $row;
    else
      $pre = $pre + $row;

    if($pre <= max($arr))
      echo " ". $arr[$pre-1] ." ";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Output when 14 element:

```
1 6 11
2 7 12
3 8 13
4 9 14
5 10
```

Output when 11 element:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8
```

Output when 13 element:

```
1 6 11
2 7 12
3 8 13
4 9
5 10
```

Comment: yes jeni very easy.. I add new answer that add result in table.