# PHP Array Combination - One to many

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry if a solution exists anywhere else, but I couldn't find one.

I have the following array:

```
$data = array(
    array('a', 'b', 'c'),
    array('e', 'f', 'g'),
    array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
);
```

I am trying hard to write a function that will give an array like:

```
a
    e
        w
        x
        y
        z
    f
        w
        x
        y
        z
    g
        w
        x
        y
        z
b
    e
        w
        x
        y
        z
    f
        w
        x
        y
        z
    g
        w
        x
        y
        z
c
    e
        w
        x
        y
        z
    f
        w
        x
        y
        z
    g
        w
        x
        y
        z
```

**The major problem here is that the number of source arrays and their lengths keep changing always. So a function should be capable of handling any data given to it.**

I tried to come up with something like this:

```
function testfunc($data){
    $arrayDepth = count($data);
    foreach($data as $key=>$d){
        foreach($d as $e){
            echo $e . "\n";
            if($key < $arrayDepth){
                array_shift($data);
                testfunc($data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output I got was:

```
a
e
w
x
y
z
f
g
w
x
y
z
b
w
x
y
z
c
e
f
g
w
x
y
z
```

I am stuck for almost a day with no proper solution. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What did you achieve so far? Showing some of the relevant code will surely help you getting good answers. Don't expect that a lot of users will provide you with ready-to-use algorithms if you don't show that you already thought about the problem.

Comment: i am not sure that i understand what are you trying to do, but the solutions seems like a classic recursion. just walk-through the arrays layer by layer, building the new structure (that is because of the unknown number and depth of array elements).

Comment: It looks quiet too simple. Is your question written correctly and with all requirements?

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig - Thanks. I have now added details to the question.

Comment: I think this guy is taking the same class as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804693/small-sorting-algorithm-in-php

Comment: @Mailo - Yes. All requirements are there. I too thought it's simple but don't know why I couldn't come up with a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recursion *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) is your friend:

```
function product($arrays) {
    if(count($arrays) === 1) {
        return $arrays[0];
    }
    else {
        $result = array();
        foreach($arrays[0] as $value) {
            $result[$value] = product(array_slice($arrays, 1));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/euH2hkme)

Comment: What??! Is that it? Oh goodness! Thanks Felix, for that quick solution.

Comment: Well, I don't know if you really want to get an array of arrays, but yeah, that is one way to solve it. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Non-recursive version.  This should run fast!

```
$result = end($data);

if ($result === false)
{
   return false; // or Array or what makes sense for an empty array.
}

$higherArr = prev($data);

while ($higherArr !== false)
{
   // Set the orignal array to be the one that you built previously.
   $orig = $result;
   $result = array();

   foreach ($higherArr as $higherKey)
   {
      $result[$higherKey] = $orig;
   }

   $higherArr = prev($data);
}

echo 'Finished with: ' . var_export($result, true);
```