# Outputting array in sections PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So i am using php for my school works controlled assessment and I need to output an array of user ID's in sections.

However it must function in this way:

- The Array must be in 3 segments of UIDS
- The UIDS cannot be repeated 
  and the array sections will be added to a time table.

So there are 10 UIDS and they must be split and assorted as follows:

```
Split 1  // The remainder is also not forgotten about
1,4,7,10

Split 2  // Vertical assorted 
2,5,8

Split 3
3,6,9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Modulo for that

```
<?php

$uids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$split = [
    0 => [],
    1 => [],
    2 => [],
];

foreach ($uids as $index => $value) {
    $split[$index % 3][] = $value;
}

var_dump($split);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=> int(1)
    [1]=> int(4)
    [2]=> int(7)
    [3]=> int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=> int(2)
    [1]=> int(5)
    [2]=> int(8)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=> int(3)
    [1]=> int(6)
    [2]=> int(9)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579702/split-an-array-into-n-arrays-php